# Create view error as statement must be only one in the batch

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the first time I'm trying to create a view in t-sql but I'm receiving an error stating: CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch.

Why is it giving me this error and how can it be fixed?

I looked at some examples but still quite not sure on what I need to do.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[League_Table_Insert]
    @LeagueName VARCHAR(30)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    CREATE VIEW League_Table AS  
    SELECT
        TeamName AS Team, 
        COUNT(*) Played, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 1 END) Wins, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN AwayScore > HomeScore THEN 1 END) Losses, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1 END) Draws, 
        SUM(HomeScore) Goals_Scored, 
        SUM(AwayScore) Goals_Against, 
        SUM(HomeScore) - SUM(AwayScore) Goal_Difference,
        SUM(
              CASE WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 3 ELSE 0 END 
            + CASE WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) Points

    FROM
    (
        SELECT TeamName, HomeScore, AwayScore FROM dbo.Team t INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture f ON t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID WHERE LeagueName = @LeagueName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TeamName, HomeScore, AwayScore FROM dbo.Team t INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture f ON t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID WHERE LeagueName = @LeagueName
    ) matches

    GROUP BY TeamName
    ORDER BY Points DESC, Goal_Difference DESC;
```

Comment: Please show your entire query. Also, you cannot use a variable in a view.

Comment: You can not use @Variable to create view..

Comment: @FelixPamittan that is the entire query, I just placed create view on the top but I'm assuming that's incorrect?

Comment: Do i need to remove the create view from the top and do a separate create view below the query?

Comment: Whilst it may be possible to achieve what you're trying to do with dynamic SQL, it's not the right way to go about it. See @FelixPamittan's answer below for how to do this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a `VIEW` inside a function. Also, you cannot use a variable inside a `VIEW`. What you want is a table-valued function. Here is a create script for an Inline Table-Valued Function (iTVF):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.League_Table (
    @LeagueName     VARCHAR(MAX)
) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT
    TeamName AS Team, 
    COUNT(*) Played, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 1 END) Wins, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN AwayScore > HomeScore THEN 1 END) Losses, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1 END) Draws, 
    SUM(HomeScore) Goals_Scored, 
    SUM(AwayScore) Goals_Against, 
    SUM(HomeScore) - SUM(AwayScore) Goal_Difference,
    SUM(
          CASE WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 3 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) Points

FROM
(
    SELECT TeamName, HomeScore, AwayScore FROM dbo.Team t INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture f ON t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID WHERE LeagueName = @LeagueName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TeamName, HomeScore, AwayScore FROM dbo.Team t INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture f ON t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID WHERE LeagueName = @LeagueName
) matches

GROUP BY TeamName;
```

Note that I removed the `ORDER BY` clause because it's not allowed in inline functions. Otherwise, you'll get an error stating:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

Then, to use it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.League_Table('Sample League Name') s
ORDER BY Points DESC, Goal_Difference DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187926.aspx) documentation clearly states below:

The following statements cannot be used anywhere in the body of a stored procedure

> CREATE AGGREGATE
>   CREATE SCHEMA
>   SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT
>   CREATE DEFAULT
>   CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER
>   SET SHOWPLAN_XML
>   CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION
>   CREATE or ALTER VIEW
>   USE database_name
>   CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE
>   SET PARSEONLY
>   CREATE RULE
>   SET SHOWPLAN_ALL